# Hosting angualrjs 2 on apache web server

Tags: angular

Is there a way to deploy or host Angular JS 2 on Apache Web Server?

I just want to know the recommended method and best practice around that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that helps you:

1. There is discussion the similar problem https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11884
2. And some instructions how to do it https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2